# SQL Server PIVOT - Removing Null Values to 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

very quick question, I would like to remove nulls and it seems when I try to add `ISNULL(LoanAmount, 0)` in @strQuery it gives me an error.  And it is really important for me to remove those null values and replace it with 0,

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @LoanTypeDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @strQuery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @strColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @LoanTypeDesc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(lt.[Description]) 
                FROM LoanType lt
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @strQuery = 'SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT TOP 1000 EmployeeID,
    LoanAmount,
    lt.[Description]
FROM LoanContract lc
INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
ORDER BY EmployeeID ASC
) src
PIVOT(
SUM(LoanAmount)
FOR Description IN (' + @LoanTypeDesc + ')
) piv;'

EXECUTE (@strQuery)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove null values. I have created list of Pivoted columns with handling NULL in `@SELECT_COLUMNS`. And if you want you can append any other columns like `EmployeeID`  to `@SELECT_COLUMNS`.

```
DECLARE @LoanTypeDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @strQuery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @strColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Creating column list with appending ISNULL
DECLARE @SELECT_COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @SELECT_COLUMNS = @SELECT_COLUMNS+ 'ISNULL( '+ QUOTENAME(lt.[Description])  +',0),'
                FROM LoanType lt
SELECT @SELECT_COLUMNS= SUBSTRING(@SELECT_COLUMNS,1,LEN(@SELECT_COLUMNS)-1);


SELECT @LoanTypeDesc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(lt.[Description]) 
                FROM LoanType lt
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

--Making Select columns from @SELECT_COLUMNS instead of *
SET @strQuery = 'SELECT '+@SELECT_COLUMNS +' 
FROM (
SELECT TOP 1000 EmployeeID,
    LoanAmount,
    lt.[Description]
FROM LoanContract lc
INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
ORDER BY EmployeeID ASC
) src
PIVOT(
SUM(LoanAmount)
FOR Description IN (' + @LoanTypeDesc + ')
) piv;'

EXECUTE (@strQuery)
```